# neo4j connection refused error on centos azure vm

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-vm

I have installed the neo4j in centos azure vm

I am trying to access it using the my local browser outside the vm. I am trying to create a 3 tier architecture where my neo4j will be sitting in one linux centos vm. But I am not able to access the neo4j.

I have added the inbound rules for ports 8080,7474,7687,7473.
Kindly help me in hosting the neo4j in azure vm. Please let me know what is the issue or configuration needed.

```
 > yum remove neo4j-4.2.0-1.noarch 
    > systemctl enable neo4j
    >  service neo4j start
    > service neo4j status 

     curl -v http://ip:7474/db/data
Neo4j.conf

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687
#dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:#{default.http.port}
#dbms.connector.http.advertised_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
#dbms.connector.https.advertised_address=:7473
# To enable HTTP logging, uncomment this line
dbms.logs.http.enabled=false
```

Comment: the listen address should probably allow 0.0.0.0

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen yes sir I have changed that. Now within the vm i am able to run but outside the vm I am not able to access. curl http://localhost:7474/
{
  "management" : "http://localhost:7474/db/manage/",
  "data" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/",
  "bolt" : "bolt://localhost:7687"
}